# What the different between these two packages : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage and Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Files

Tags: azure, xamarin, storage, azure-blob-storage

I currently need to store files into azure blob storage. I come across two different resources but not sure the second set of packages are for.

I probably only need the top two packages for accessing the Blob Storage.

```
    using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
```

From the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-blob-storage, it say Connect to Azure Storage in your Xamarin.Forms app.

```
 using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Files;
 using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Files.Metadata;
 using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Files.Sync;
 using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Sync;
```

Problem with the first set of package required me to use Shared Library not PCL.

Answer (score 0):

WindowsAzure.Storage (the first set of namespaces) is the client library for Azure Storage services. Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.Files (the second set of namespaces) is a client extension for Azure Mobile Apps.

If you are using the Mobile Apps SDK and want to work within its abstractions then it makes sense to use the second library. If you want to have access to all of the features of Azure Storage then it makes sense to use the first project.

As of version 8.0, the Azure Storage client contains a netstandard 1.0 façade, which works like a PCL.

Comment: I saw a link of tutorial in msdn which showing how to do offline sync data for the second library, is it possible to do the same with the first library.

Comment: The Mobile Apps SDK internally uses the Storage Client Library, so it's possible in the sense that you can build such a solution. If you are looking for existing mobile solutions such as offline sync then the Mobile Apps SDK sounds like what you want to use.